# How to run vbscript command from cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, shell, cmd.exe, vbscript

(I don't speak English. Hope you understand.)

Hi, I have the following VBS command.

```
set shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") : shell.run "notepad"
```

(Start notepad, but from vbs.) I want to run this command from CMD. I can't do it like:

```
C:\>wscript set shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") : shell.run "notepad"
```

I can do:

```
C:\>wscript script.vbs
```

but I must have the command in another file. I want to run it from the command prompt. How could I do it?

Thank you for the answers, Andrew

Comment: You might want to reword your question, otherwise you'll end up with an answer which will be along the lines of "call `notepad` from the command line". You want a way to pass and execute VBScript on the command line.

Comment: I know I can, this is only the example. Actually I have something that you can only run in vbs.